# Calling onscroll event of an element inside the created function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to listen to a scroll event inside the specific element but it doesn't seem to be working inside the created function, below is my attempt and [here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mejuliver/8hxrt9eq/18/).

Try to un-comment the scroll event outside the Vue instance and you'll know

```
new Vue({
  el : '#vueapp',
  data : {
    showSearchBar : 0
  },
  created(){
    const _self = this;

    document.querySelector('#app').onscroll = function() {

    alert();

        if(document.querySelector('#app').scrollTop >= 10) {
            _self.showSearchBar = 1;
        }else{
            _self.showSearchBar = 0;
        }
    }
    // --
  }
});
```

Comment: you root vue id is "vueapp", but you tried to find id "app". Could be the reason?

Comment: either vueapp or app, should cause no conflict since they are unique ids, I tried using the #app before as a root vue id but still not working.

Comment: put your onscroll function inside the `mounted` hook instead of `created`

Comment: @Sovalina yes, you're right, because created does not render the doom yet so mounted should be the answer and not created

Answer (score 0):

While moving the event handler to `mounted` (as suggested by Sovalina in the comments) works, it isn't the Vue way to do this.

With Vue, you should embed the event handler information inside the html template instead:

(Basing this on the code you posted on jsfiddle)

```
<div id="vueapp">
    <div id="app" @scroll="handleScroll">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
    el : '#vueapp',
    data : {
        showSearchBar : 0
    },
    methods: {
        handleScroll(evt) {
            if(evt.target.scrollTop >= 10) {
                this.showSearchBar = 1;
            }else{
                this.showSearchBar = 0;
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: scroll event occur on the element .page__content and not on the root #app

Comment: its a page content scroll event

Comment: Your java script code shows the scroll event happening on the `#app` element